# Integration region: Over a Circle Segment

Tags: integration

I need to integrate over a region of a circle the looks like a pac-man:

Think of a point a slight distance (say distance $r_2$) to the right of the centre of a circle (the back of the pacman's mouth) and then around an angle that covers the entire body of the pacman: what limits do I put on the double integral?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the area of the wedge you are removing from the circle, or the area of the region that is part of the circle, you can compute it without the use of calculus.

Take the circle with radius  $ \ R \ $ to be centered at the origin, with the point you want to remove the wedge from to be located at $ \ (r_2 , 0) \ $ , and half of the opening angle of the wedge you wish to remove to be $ \ \theta \ $ . We will call half of the opening angle of the wedge *as measured from the origin* (center of circle) $ \ \phi \ . $  The area of the wedge coming from the center is $ \ 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} R^2 \phi \ $ .  This leaves us with two triangles also to be "removed" from the circle, with a total area of $ \ 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} R r_2 \sin(180º - \phi) =  R r_2 \sin \phi \ . $

The remaining complication is to find the measure of the angle $ \ \phi \ $ .  In the triangles we are describing, the side opposite $ \ \theta \ $ is the radius $ \ R \ $ .  The angle with its vertex at the origin is $ \ 180º - \phi \ $ , so the angle opposite the side of length $ \ r_2 \ $ is $ \ 180º - \theta - (180º - \phi) = \phi - \theta \ . $  The "Law of Sines" then gives us

$$\frac{\sin \theta}{R} \ = \ \frac{\sin (\phi - \theta)}{r_2} . $$

This is what you would need to evaluate to obtain the value of $ \ \phi \ $ .

The total area of the off-center wedge is then

$$\ R^2 \phi \ +  R r_2 \sin \phi \ , $$

so the area you are concerned with within the circle is

$$\pi R^2 \ - \ (R^2 \phi \ +  R r_2 \sin \phi) \ = \ R^2 (\pi - \phi) \ -  R r_2 \sin \phi \ . $$

I don't think there's a nice way to describe the region you want in polar coordinates, since you wish to measure from an off-center point...

$$ \\ $$

**ADDENDUM (7/19) --**

I wasn't clear earlier as to whether you were simply finding the area of the region or integrating a function over it.  As mentioned in the comments, Cartesian coordinates will be easier to use, since an essential symmetry is lost that would make polar coordinates suitable.

If you are placing the vertex of the sector to the right of the origin at $ \ (r_2 , 0 ) \ , $ (so $ \ r_2 \ $ is positive), and the "upper" line for the "wedge" makes an angle $ \ \theta \ $ to the negative $ \ x-$axis, then the slope of the line is $ \ -\tan \theta \ $ and the equation of the line is 
$$ \ y - 0 \ = \ ( -\tan \theta) \cdot ( x - r_2 ) \ \Rightarrow \ y  \ = \ r_2 \tan \theta \ - \ (\tan \theta) \cdot  x \ . $$

You would need to find where this line intersects the circle $ \ x^2 + y^2  =  R^2 \ , $ which will require solving the quadratic equation

$$ x^2 + (r_2 \tan \theta \ - \ [\tan \theta] \cdot  x)^2  =  R^2  $$

$$\Rightarrow (\sec^2 \theta) \cdot x^2 \ - \ (2r_2 \tan^2 \theta) \cdot x \ + \ (  r_2^2 \tan^2 \theta \ - \ R^2) \ = \ 0 \ .  $$

You will want the "negative" solution for the intersection to the left of the origin, which we'll call $ \ -X \ $ .

In the "upper" half-plane, from $ \ x = -X \ \ \text{to} \ \ x = r_2 \ , $ we would be integrating between the oblique line for the "edge of the wedge" and the upper semicircle, then between the $ \ x-$axis and the semicircle from $ \ x = r_2 \ \ \text{to} \ \ x = R \ . $  So your integration becomes

$$\int_{-X}^{r_2} \int_{r_2 \tan \theta \ - \ [\tan \theta] \cdot  x}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}  \ f(x,y) \ \ dy \ dx  \ + \  \int_{r_2}^{R} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}  \ f(x,y) \ \ dy \ dx  \ . $$

If $ \ f(x,y) \ $ has suitable symmetry about the $ \ x-$axis, you could then simply double this result for the integration over the entire "Pac-Man" region.  Otherwise, you'll need a second integration for the "lower" half-region,

$$\int_{-X}^{r_2} \int^{-r_2 \tan \theta \ + \ [\tan \theta] \cdot  x}_{-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}  \ f(x,y) \ \ dy \ dx  \ + \  \int_{r_2}^{R} \int^{0}_{-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}  \ f(x,y) \ \ dy \ dx  \ . $$

[Well, losing symmetry generally makes these calculations less "pretty" and more complicated...]

Comment: Thanks for this, though I'm not finding an area, im integration over a region - I definitely need calculus; could it be done in Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: In other words, you're integrating some function over that region?   It shouldn't be too bad, since you could easily get the slope and equation of the line from the off-center point to the cirumference of the circle, then integrate a region between that line and the upper semi-circle until you reach the off-center point, then the region under the semi-circle from the off-center point onward to the edge of the circle.  Cartesian coordinates are probably much easier for this problem.

Comment: So the line has equation mx + c, and the semi-circle Root(R^2 - x^2)? Am I right about the semi-cicle equation?

Comment: I think I got it - thanks for this! X

Comment: @AlexanderGiles  Sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner.  I've amended my answer if you are still interested.  You are correct in your earlier comment as to the equations you proposed using.

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates perhaps?

$$\int_A f(x) dx dy  = \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\int_0^R f(r,\theta)r drd\theta$$

Comment: But the integration is not between 0 and R as the distance from the point off centre to the perimeter is changing; what you give is over the radius of the entire circle, but im not integrating from the centre, I'm integrating over an angle and over a distance from the off-centre point to the perimeter - you understand? 0 to R and Theta1 Theta2 etc gives me a circle segment centred at the centre of the circle, I need it off centre...